# How to write the path in php fopen?

Tags: php, path

I have some problems with the relative and absolute paths in php fopen.
I have the following directories:

```
project:
    scripts:
        myscript.php
    logs:
        mylog.log
```

I want to open `mylog.log` from `myscript.php` and I don't know how to specify the path. I tried

```
fopen('../logs/mylog.log', "a")
```

but it won't work.
Thanks.

LE: Thanks for you answers.

Comment: There is no "it does not work", there might be error messages instead.

Comment: Is it returning an error? The error should reflect the resolved path being accessed. Also, check permissions.

Comment: @str - Are you kidding? I've gotten a *TON* of doesn't works.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In php, there are a couple of global constants that could be of help to you. Namely, `__DIR__` gives you the directory of the current file (`'.'` just gives you the directory of the root script executing).

So what you want is:

```
fopen(__DIR__ . '/../logs/mylog.log', "a")
```

Comment: Indeed. `dirname(__FILE__)` can be used for portability to PHP installations under 5.3.0.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which gives the document root of the virtual host.

eg: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/log/mylog.log"`

Comment: You are assuming he is running this via a web server and not the command line.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
fopen(__DIR__ . '/../logs/mylog.log', "a");
```

or in PHP < 5.3:

```
fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../logs/mylog.log', "a");
```